# Linq where clause problem

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, clause

I thought I'd seen somewhere a while back an example of `where` clause which called a function that gave a `bool` result ,and I can't find it again so I'll outline my problem.

I have a collection

```
Dictionary< string, KeyValuePair < int, int >>
```

in which I want to have a query for the `string` key.  On the surface that is simple but unfortunately the string (over which I have no control) is an encoded co-ordinate of a grid cell.

The query is to retrieve entries (as the type of `Dictionary`) which fall into a certain part of the grid.  Placing a function call `cells.Where(c => isWithinArea(c.Key, area))` compiles but does not work. The function never gets called.

I would welcome any suggestions to make this work with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: You'll have to post the code.  As you describe it, everything sounds fine.

Comment: "does not work" - you'll have to describe what it does, and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 11):

The most likely reasons the function is never called would be if the sequence you're "where-ing" has no elements, or you are never invoking the enumerator at all. LINQ is lazy-evaluated, which means none of the expressions you've provided are actually invoked until you start to `foreach` or `ToList()`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the latter.  Good catch.

Comment: Yeah, I bet the latter is exactly the issue here. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
cells.Keys.Where(key => isWithinArea(key, area))
```